# Single consumer-multiple threads vs multiple consumers

Tags: mysql, multithreading, algorithm, transactions, locking

By googling it seems that it is not really recommended to use a table in order to implement a producer/consumer pattern. The most tricky part is having multiple consumers.
I am not sure why. If instead of having multiple processes/threads trying to claim records and we should make sure that they don't claim the same ones etc, isn't it the same to have a have a single consumer that fetches records, passes them to forked processes which do the processing and in the end update the relevant records?
It seems that this design has the same result as having multiple consumers but non of the disadvantages.
Am I misunderstanding something e.g. transaction wise, locking etc?

Comment: In the case of boss/workers, you don't need locking as nothing competes with boss giving jobs.

Comment: @mpapec:That is my point.Since no locking is needed why most articles discuss about multiple workers/consumers and contention over the queue etc?Master consumer and multiple helper threads seem better.Am I missing something?

Comment: It depends on the architecture, ie. in case of web server you have threads which may compete for same resources.

Comment: @mpapec:I see what you mean.But what if we leave out this case and focus on the producer/consumer idea, is there any issue with a single consumer of the source handing over to multiple threads?

Comment: @Jim: Basically, you've implemented a semaphore specialized to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I find it much easier to work with multiple consumers that all service a single thread-safe queue. The general structure of the program is this:

```
var queue = some thread-safe queue

// multiple consumer threads that all do this
consumer:
    while (queue.Take(item))
    {
        process(item);
    }
```

Note that the queue's `Take` method does a non-busy wait (usually using a [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) of some kind.

The producer adds things to the queue:

```
producer:
    while (items available from input)
    {
        queue.Add(item);
    }
```

This, to me, is a much simpler design because I just have to set it up once. The queue data structure is designed such that it supports multiple producers and multiple consumers. It handles all of the synchronization for you.

If you do it the other way, with a single consumer thread servicing the queue and firing off worker threads as necessary, it gets messy. The consumer thread has to keep track of how many worker threads are currently running, and receive notification when a worker has finished. The worker threads have to concern themselves not only with processing the items, but also notifying when they're done with their work. The result is that your code is either continually creating and destroying threads, or you're using explicit synchronization and inter-thread communication mechanisms to essentially suspend and restart threads. All of this is possible, but it's much more complex than communicating through a single thread-safe queue that supports non-busy waits.

There are variations. You could have a single thread that gets items from the input and fires off worker threads, queueing other workers or work items when the number of items to be processed exceeds the number of available workers. This is just another level of complexity in the producer, and doesn't really change things.

I can't say which would be more efficient, although it's probably a moot point. Any differences in execution time are likely so small in comparison to the total that they're irrelevant. For me, it's more important that my programs be correct and easy to understand. A simple producer/consumer model with a shared queue is much easier to code, understand, and prove correct than my own custom dispatcher that uses a lot of explicit synchronization.

Comment: Yes but my original question is about implementing a queue via a database table in mysql. So how is the "queue" you are describing implemented?

Comment: @Jim: Have a single thread get records from the database and place them into an in-memory queue. That's your "producer." The consumers, then, read from that queue.

Answer (score 0):

The cost of contention with multiple consumer threads is that they must block while waiting on a lock to consume.  With your suggested pattern serving multiple threads, the threads still have to block while waiting to consume.  It's just that they are waiting on the "single consumer" instead of waiting on a simple lock.  Since the "single consumer" will be more complex than a simple lock, it will be less efficient and more bug prone.